# how to sum data by month and store them in the first day of the month

Tags: r, date, aggregate

Lets say I have a data frame as follows:

```
gageID    date        flow_cms
1011000 1937-02-19   25.768334
1011000 1937-02-20   24.918828
1011000 1937-02-21   24.069322
```

I want to aggregate the rows that have the same month summing the flow, and
store the result into a new data value: the first day of every month; in order to obtain the following output:

```
gageID  date  sum_monthly_flow
1011000 1937-02-01  500.2222
1011000 1937-03-01  589.222
```

I'm using this line:

```
>rowsum(qfile$flow_cms, format(qfile$date, '%Y-%m-01'))
```

and I obtain the right sum, but I want also to reduce the record days in
a unique day: the first of every month! with the strip shows above, R cannot
recognize the left coloumn as data (or date).

Help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure your "date" column is properly formatted as a date object in R:

```
qfile$date <- as.Date(qfile$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Then we can use `format` to extract the month and year, and `group_by` that for a sum and take the first date:

```
library(dplyr)
qfile %>% mutate(monthyear = as.character(format(date, "%m-%Y"))) %>%
          arrange(date) %>% 
          group_by(monthyear) %>%
          summarise(date=date[1], flow = sum(flow_cms))
```

This will give you the first taken record for each month in the data.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Jeremycg!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
df
   gageID       date  flow_cms
1 1011000 1937-02-19  25.76833
2 1011000 1937-02-20  24.91883
3 1011000 1937-02-21  24.06932
4 1011000 1937-03-20  12.22200
5 1011000 1937-03-01 589.22200

df1 = aggregate(list(flow_cms=df$flow_cms),by=list(dates=cut(as.POSIXct(df$date),"month")),sum)

df1
       dates  flow_cms
1 1937-02-01  74.75648
2 1937-03-01 601.44400
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` and `lubridate` you can try:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(qfile)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(gageID, date = lubridate::floor_date(date, "month"))]
```

> ```
>     gageID       date  flow_cms
> 1: 1011000 1937-02-01  74.75648
> 2: 1011000 1937-03-01 601.44400
> ```

Note that it is assumed that `date` is already of class `Date` and that `gageID` is another grouping parameter.

Alternatively, the call to a function from another package can be avoided using `data.table`'s own `mday()` function (thanks to @Henrik):

```
setDT(qfile)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(gageID, date = date - mday(date) + 1)]
```

#### Data

Here, [Abdou's sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33110498/3817004)  is used:

```
qfile <- structure(list(gageID = c(1011000L, 1011000L, 1011000L, 1011000L, 
1011000L), date = structure(c(-12004, -12003, -12002, -11975, 
-11994), class = "Date"), flow_cms = c(25.76833, 24.91883, 24.06932, 
12.222, 589.222)), .Names = c("gageID", "date", "flow_cms"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```