# How to sum multiple dataframe's variables by month

Tags: r, date, sum

I have got a very similar issue addressed here [how to sum data by month and store them in the first day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109673/how-to-sum-data-by-month-and-store-them-in-the-first-day-of-the-month)

The only thing that differs from the above post is that my real data.frame has got 300 variables that need to be grouped and summed by month.

Something like this:

```
    date        gauge1   gauge2  gauge3
 1937-02-19   25.768334  23.98   111.3
 1937-02-20   24.918828  21.987  33.9
 1937-02-21   24.069322  19.96   18.981
```

Desired output:

```
 date         gauge1    gauge2   gauge3
 1937-02-01   3328.98   2229.0   11541.3
 1937-03-01   222.19    1176.8   1098.8
 1937-04-01   1124.8    3395.15  1558.9
```

Based on @jeremycg answer I tried:

```
library(dplyr)
qfile %>% mutate(monthyear = as.character(format(date, "%m-%Y"))) %>%
          arrange(date) %>% 
          group_by(monthyear) %>%
          summarise(date=date[1], flow = sum(df[, c(2:4)])
```

But it does not work.

Any help would really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: To make your question useful for other, please, explain *why* the `dplyr` attempt failed. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know why it did not work..sorry

Comment: Did you get an error message?

Comment: yep but can't remember it. I am sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *all* columns of your data set except the `date` column need to be grouped and summed you can try:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(qfile)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = lubridate::floor_date(date, "month")]
```

> ```
>     lubridate   gauge1 gauge2  gauge3
> 1: 1937-02-01 74.75648 65.927 164.181
> ```

Or, if you want to rename the grouping variable:

```
setDT(qfile)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = (date = lubridate::floor_date(date, "month"))]
```

> ```
>          date   gauge1 gauge2  gauge3
> 1: 1937-02-01 74.75648 65.927 164.181
> ```

Following @Henrik' suggestion, the call to a function from another package can be avoided by using `data.table`'s built-in `mday()` function:

```
setDT(qfile)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = (date = date - mday(date) + 1)]
```